# Is there a way to configure separated swagger url for each controller?

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, swagger-2.0

I'm trying to configure swagger 2 in springboot project to separate documentation for each controller class.

Can't find such thing in documentation.

Example controller:

```java
@Api(description = "giftcard controller")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/giftcard")
public class GiftCardController {

    @ApiOperation(value = "get info about requested cards")

    @GetMapping(value = "/getInfo")
    public HttpStatus getInfo(String id) {
        return HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE;
    }
}
```

swagger.yaml

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  title: Sample API
  description: API description in Markdown.
  version: 1.0.0
host: api.example.com
basePath: /v1
schemes:
  - https
paths:
  /users:
    get:
      summary: Returns a list of users.
      description: Optional extended description in Markdown.
      produces:
        - application/json
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
```

Swagger- SpringBoot Enable:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {}
```